# How to stop and start the mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

When I'm use the find command to locate the MySQL location, it returns the below paths. But, I want to restart the MySQL. If I stop the path (/usr/bin/mysql) it shows the error

[Access denied to user 'root'@'localhost' with password='NO]'

so, Which MySQL will be get restart in the below paths ?

/usr/bin/mysql

/usr/share/mysql

/usr/lib/mysql

/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql

/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/mysql

/usr/lib64/mysql

/var/lib/mysql

/var/lib/mysql/mysql

Comment: Is the error the same for each path?

Comment: @Andrius Narusevicius No, The error is only for /usr/bin/mysql. for others it is showing as a directory

Answer (score 4):

to stop mysql account is:

`sudo mysqladmin -h localhost -u root -p shutdown`

to start is: 
`sudo systemctl start mysql.service`

to confirm:

`sudo mysql -h localhost -u root -p`

NB:
the default password for root account is `root`

**not sure but i think this closes connection for all accounts & also starts for all accounts though you have stop using an account with privilege access/root access by using the grant statement.

example

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'username'@'localhost';`

source http://www.luciopanasci.it/Ebooks/MySQL%20Cookbook,%203rd%20Edition.pdf 
page 2 topic 1.1**

Answer (score 1):

As root, run
`service mysqld restart`

If that does not work, try
`/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`

Instead of restart you can use :

`start` to start mysql

`stop` to stop it

Answer (score 0):

If Mysql is running as a service:

```
sudo service mysql restart;
```

or

```
sudo service path/to/mysql restart;
```

**Edit:**

check if mysql is running

```
service --status-all
service --status-all | grep mysql
```

Comment: Do you have mysql running in the first place? and how did you install it?

Comment: Mysqld is running, But, there is no mysql

Comment: So many times I restarted that, But my changes in my.cnf file is not effecting in database

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start/stop/restart
```

It may be called mysqld or mysql-server or something like that. If you're on Ubuntu, you have to do

```
service mysql start/stop/restart
```

there it may be mysqld or mysql-server or something like this as well.

Comment: Hohenfold I'm using linux. There is no mysql located in /etc/init.d/  Is it possible # /etc/init.d/mysql

Answer (score 0):

If Mysql is running, use

**To Restart:** `service mysqld restart`

Other command which can be used if necessary are given below.

**To Stop:** `service mysqld stop`

**To Start:** `service mysqld start`